# Inserting HTML form submissions into MySQL table (using PDO)

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, pdo

I'm trying to create a webpage that has multiple forms that people will fill, click submit, PHP will handle running a query to insert all the data into the table, in their respective fields.

I created one that submitted one field completely fine, and as soon as I expanded it to 5 fields I realised I didn't know how to handle the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Asset Pass</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Asset Submission</h1>
<p>Connection status: <?php include '../mysqlconnect.php'; echo $db . " active"; ?></p>

<form method="post">
<div><label for="type">Type:
<br/><input type="text" name="type" id="type"/></label></div>
<div><label for="name">Name:
<br/><input type="text" name="name" id="name"/></label></div>
<div><label for="desc">Description:
<br/><input type="text" name="desc" id="desc"/></label></div>
<div><label for="loc">Location:
<br/><input type="text" name="loc" id="loc"/></label></div>
<div><label for="label">Label:
<br/><input type="text" name="label" id="label"/></label></div>
<div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="GO"/></div>
</form>

<?php
#function aquery($asset) {
#   include '../mysqlconnect.php';
#   $conn->query("INSERT INTO kit VALUES ('$asset', '$name', '$desc', '$loc', '$label');");
#}

if ($_POST['submit']) {
        include '../mysqlconnect.php';
        foreach ($_POST['type'] as $key => $value)
        {
            $type =  $_POST['type'] [$key];
            $name =  $_POST['name'] [$key];
            $desc =  $_POST['desc'] [$key];
            $loc =   $_POST['loc']  [$key];
            $label = $_POST['label'][$key];

            $sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO Kit VALUES ('$type', '$name', '$desc', '$loc', '$label');");
        }
}

##  $asset = $_POST['name'];
#   aquery($asset);
#   printf("<h3>Entry Accepted</h3>" . "<br/><br/>" . "<strong>Submission: </strong>" . $asset . "<br/><br/>");

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for the butchered code - the commented bits at the top and bottom are the original fragments of code I tried using, the bit in the middle is a suggested online solution, and something close to what I think would work. I'm using PDO btw!

Comment: There is only one form in this code but you speak of multiple forms. I'm not sure of what you are asking for here. Is the HTML part OK or do you need help to create the forms?

Comment: Does the suggested code not work?  if so what is it doing or not doing?

Comment: Sorry, I meant multiple FIELDS, not forms. One form, multiple inputs, the HTML part is fine but I'm having a hard time finding the right code to take the submitted values (type, name, description, etc) and actually put them into my table on the same row, in the corresponding fields.

So if I put in "Monitor, Samsung 24 inch, Sam's Monitor" in the fields, and clicked GO, it'd create a row under my Kit table, with those values populating that row.

Comment: Answering your question NathanOliver, I open the page and immediately am faced with, under the form, " Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\xampp\htdocs\dw\dw\phpqueries.php on line 30", line 30 is "if ($_POST['submit']) {"

Comment: $key the undefined index?

Comment: Your table column names are missing in your query.Refer this page http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Insert-and-Update-Statement-Use-Prepared-Statement-P552.html

Comment: $_POST['type'] is a value from the form and $_POST['type'] ['key'] is invalid. Remove that foreach loop

Comment: Alaksandar you gave me exactly what I needed! I'm still getting to grips with mysql and I didn't know how $_POST and isset worked properly, so now I'm using the code:

    if (isset($_POST['submit'];
    $type = $_POST['type']; for type and $name = $_POST['name']; for name, etc

and then just querying the vars with the column names included. Now I just need to learn how to sanitise the input to escape " and ' :)

Comment: Thanks again - figured it all out.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand how $_POST and isset worked properly.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
    include '../mysqlconnect.php';
    $type = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'type', FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
```

and so forth, works perfectly.